# Having Trouble Understanding how to Avoid Cross-Origin Contamination in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

I'm getting errors for cross-origin contamination in the following code, and I can't figure out why. I thought cross-origin contamination occurred when you tried to extract an image from an external server, but the image is from a local directory.

```
var image = new Image();
$(image).on("load", function() {
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 1080/scale, 1920/scale);

    /*Error occurs here */
    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0,
        this.width / scale,
        this.height / scale);
    var pixels = imageData.data;

    ...
});
image.src = "test2.jpg";
```

Comment: Define "local". Is this file actually hosted via an HTTP server, or are you accessing it via `file://`?

Comment: I'm accessing it via file://.

Comment: Most (all?) browsers don't allow access to the local file system. Depending on your browser you can override this (e.g., Chrome supports the `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag). Whether you *should* do this or not is dependent on how confident you feel in your other layers of security and how you use the web.

Comment: I'm using Chrome right now to test everything, so I could do that temporarily, but if, let's say, I hosted everything on AWS, would I avoid the cross-contamination issue?

Comment: As long as it's being run through an HTTP server you should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The local file system is declared to be cross-origin and will taint the canvas. This is a good declaration given that your most sensitive information is probably on a local file system.

Here are some ways to be compliant with CORS security:

- Install a web server on your local computer and serve both your images and .html/.css/.js files on that server.  PHP & IIS both have excellent local editions.
- Put your images on a CORS compliant hosting service (imagur.com is one among others)
- For small projects, it sometimes works to put both the image and webpage files all on the desktop.

Comment: That's where I get confused, because the image is in a folder in the workspace. Shouldn't the webpages and images be considered all on the desktop if they're all in one directory?

Comment: Nope, all the files have to be actually on the desktop.  Even this might not work if the image files contain property information indicating that they did not originate locally.  I recommend just installing a local web server unless this is a 1-off project for you.  ;-)

Comment: Huh, alright. I'll install a local web server then. Thanks a lot for the help!